# Laravel behind AWS ELB has incorrect hostname even with X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, proxy, amazon-elb

Having a Laravel project running behind ELB, I configured the TrustProxy middleware with the following :

```php
protected $proxies = '*';
protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB;
```

And my env has

```
APP_URL=https://mylaravelapp.com
```

However, the `$_SERVER` array and `request()->headers()->all()` return an incorrect hostname, with a value similar to `xxxxxx.awselb.com`, and consequently all the `route()` methods return the same incorrect hostname. The `$_SERVER` does contain the `HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB`

Example

```php
redirect()->to('/test')->getTargetUrl();
// >> returns https://xxxxx.awselb.com/test
// expected : https://mylaravelapp.com/test

route('/test');
// >> returns https://xxxxx.awselb.com/test
// expected : https://mylaravelapp.com/test
```

Comment: The `TrustProxy` middleware does not affect the `$_SERVER` however it *should* affect the Request object and correct the hostname in that so maybe do a `dd(request())` to see what's going on there. In addition when you set APP_URL then that should override whatever is in the headers anyway, so maybe your configuration is not read correctly

Comment: `request()->headers->all()` returns the same incorrect hostname at awselb. My `APP_URL` is well configured on the proper domain that my app uses, but somehow that does not reflect on the app.

Comment: Can you share some code of what's not working? e.g what url generation method you used and what it returned vs what you expected

Comment: @apokryfos updated original question